# Using pause without increasing page number

Tags: beamer

Beamer displays page number of the form: page number/ total page at the end of the slide. This page number increases every time I use the `pause` command. Is there a way to make all the pages creating by `pause` from a single frame to have the same page number. I just don't want to discourage the listeners with too many slides. Thanks.

======== Update =======
Thanks for the comment, here is a minimal working example, I would like to have 2 pages with the same numbering 1/1 instead of 1/2 and 2/2:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}    

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{My frame}
First question?
\begin{itemize}
  \item first item
  \item second item
\end{itemize} \pause

Second question?
\begin{itemize}
  \item first item
  \item second item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `frame number` instead `page number` in

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{My frame}
  First question?
  \begin{itemize}
    \item first item
    \item second item
  \end{itemize} \pause 

  Second question?
  \begin{itemize}
    \item first item
    \item second item
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are customizing your theme and end up using `\insertpagenumber` then as @esdd suggests you need to change that to `\insertframenumber`.