# Slide numbers for animations

Tags: beamer, numbering, animations, mini-frames

The following code produces the below output

```
 \documentclass [compress]{beamer}
 \newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{6}{7.2}\selectfont}
 \usepackage{remreset}
 \usepackage{textpos}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{animate}
 \usetheme{Warsaw}
 \definecolor{ForestGreen}{RGB}{60, 140, 60}
 \setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=white,bg=ForestGreen}
 \beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{35}}{\opaqueness<2->{50}}
 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
 \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
 \leavevmode%
 \hbox{%
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette  primary}%
 \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
 \end{beamercolorbox}%
 }
 }
 \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
 \setbeamercovered{invisible}
 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
 \useoutertheme[footline=empty,subsection=false]{miniframes}
 \begin{document}
 \title{Multisource data analysis}  
 \author{Author name} 
 \institute{Biochemistry}
 \date{\today} 
 \begin{frame}[plain]
 \titlepage
 \end{frame}
 \section{Motivation} 
 \begin{frame} \frametitle {Production}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item<1-> Dynamic structures
 \item<2-> Minor components
 \item<3-> Proteins
 \end{itemize}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

I have animated the bullets in the second frame but I get new frame numbers. I would like to suppress that and have the frame number 2 for all the animated items. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191218/using-pause-without-increasing-page-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a MWE created according to [Using pause without increasing page number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191218/using-pause-without-increasing-page-number). By putting the frame number into the footer it just solves the problem with increasing page numbers.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 

\author{Authorname}   
\date{\today}
\title{Biochemistry}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}

    \section{Motivation} 
    \begin{frame} \frametitle {Production}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> Dynamic structures
            \item<2-> Minor components
            \item<3-> Proteins
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I didn't use the same layout as shown in your MWE, but the solution does what it should do: 
[image]
[image]