# Ignore \pause but count \only in beamer for slide number

Tags: beamer

Beamer displays an excessive page number because it counts each \pause command as an extra page, which it technically is in the PDF but logically isn't.

Following an [answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191218/using-pause-without-increasing-page-number), I tried
`\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}`, however that introduces the opposite problem of counting pages with the `\only` command only once, even though those are logically multiple slides.

Is there a way to ignore only `\pause` but still follow `\only` when counting page/frame numbers in the footline?

### Example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide with Pause}                                                                                                                               
This should all be slide one.\\
One\pause{} Two\pause{} Three
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide with Only}
\only<1>{This should be page 2.}
\only<2>{This should be page 3.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I use "page number", I get 5 pages. If I use "frame number", I get 2 pages. However I want to get 3 pages.

Comment: Without  see the code is impossible to know what are you doing wrong. In beamer there are page, slides and frames. If you use a theme like `Madrid` with 3 frames, each with two pauses, you will have a PDF with 9 pages and 3 frames with 3 slides each, and the counter go from 1/3 to 3/3, that is, counting frames, not slides nor pages.

Comment: @Fran: I added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The obvious solution:** tell the truth

```
\begin{frame}{Slide without Only}
This should be page 2.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide without Only}
This should be page 3.
\end{frame}
```

Full mwe:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide with Pause}
This should all be \sout{slide} frame \insertframenumber.\\
(page \insertpagenumber,  slide \insertslidenumber)\par\pause
(page \insertpagenumber,  slide \insertslidenumber)\par\pause
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide without Only}
This is the \sout{slide} frame \insertframenumber.
(page \insertpagenumber,  slide \insertslidenumber)
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide without Only}
This is \sout{slide} frame \insertframenumber.
(page \insertpagenumber,  slide \insertslidenumber)
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**The unnecessary complicated solution:** hide and lie

```
\begin{frame}{Slide with Only}
\only<1>{This should be page 2.}
\only<2>{\addtocounter{framenumber}{1}This should be page 3.}
\end{frame}
```

Full mwe:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide with Pause}
This should all be \sout{slide} frame \insertframenumber.\\
(page \insertpagenumber,  slide \insertslidenumber)\par\pause
(page \insertpagenumber,  slide \insertslidenumber)\par\pause
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide with Only}
\only<1>{This should be \sout{slide} frame \insertframenumber. 
(but page in \insertpagenumber,  slide \insertslidenumber)}
\only<2>{\addtocounter{framenumber}{1}This should be \sout{slide} frame \insertframenumber.
(but page in \insertpagenumber,  slide \insertslidenumber)}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```